# Error when using sklearn model loaded by joblib. TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I created a **VotingClassifier()** object using sklearn. Later, I save it to *voting_predictor.pkl* file using joblib. While I load it successfully, when I try to predict some data as `voting_predictor.predict(X_test)` I get the following error:

> > TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

I tried to dump/load the object with **pickle** and I got the same exact error. The code looks like this:

```
eclf1 = VotingClassifier(estimators=estimators, voting='hard')

eclf1 = eclf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = eclf1.predict(X_test)

report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
poll_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print(report)
print(poll_accuracy)

# successful object dump
filename = 'voting_predictor.pkl'
joblib.dump(eclf1, filename)

#successful object load
voting_predictor = joblib.load(filename)
# this prints the object correctly, showing all its parameters 
print(voting_predictor)

#error shows here
y_pred = voting_predictor.predict(X_test)

report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
poll_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

The `print(voting_predictor)` prints successfully the object and all its parameters. Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: The issue seems to be with your X_test. Can you try changing the dtype for X_test or give me an example of the dataframe and I can help more.

Comment: THanks for your reply, this is the iris dataset loaded from csv with pandas. As you can see, in the third command I use X_test again to predict the output and it works with no errors. The exact same command is throwing the error after loading the classifier from the object file. I also used multiple csv files, I got error in every case.

Comment: Also, the algorithms I include in the voting classifier are Random Forest, SVM and Logistic Regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the target column was the name of the classes, as string. It seems that leaving the string value without label-encoding it to some integer, was causing this error. However, in any other case, sklearn handled the string name of each class correctly, providing all metrics such as classification_report and accuracy_score without errors. The errors occurred only when I loaded the object from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while ensembling catbooster with other predictors.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761807/an-typeerror-with-votingclassifier) solution however I am looking for a more elegant one.